# mysql mklink before create database

Tags: mysql, database, directory

Is it possible to do mklink before database is created? Cause I received `Selected name conflicts with existing schema .....`. Schema was not created, just mklink in data folder.

Why do I asking about this? I would like to setup folder for each customer with WWW, MySQL & Email. To simple get diskspace usage per customer. Oh and btw I have to prevent mysql restarts. It's not so cool to restart mysql every time some customer want to create database.

Comment: I'd avoid this if at all possible. Generally fiddling with MySQL files is relying on a set of assumptions that may be wrong or change in future. Either provide each customer with their own MySQL instance, or probe the information schema to determine the database disk use estimate per customer.

Comment: @danblack Well I solved this by reverse.. I do symbolic link on folder in mysql data folder. I can still get on symbolic link correct datasize. So that's my solution :)